# OrientDB Full Text Index Search using Lucene on multiple fields

Tags: lucene, orientdb

I'm building a simple address database. Have a class called `Address` in which the addresses are broken down into fields (street, city, state, ZIP). Each field is of String type.

**I want to be able to search addresses by any word in them. Eg: find the address whether the searched word is in the street name or city name, etc. 
In other words I want the users to be able to easily search without having to specify which part of the address they are interested in.**

So I created an index like with the following command:

`create index Address.full on Address(street,city,state,ZIP) fulltext engine lucene`

But when I execute the following queries I get no results or an error message:

`select * from Address where Address.full lucene "4*"`
=> no results, should be 2 records where the zip codes are 46250 and 46256

`select * from Address where ZIP lucene "4*"`
=> Get error message: "Cannot evaluate lucene condition without index configuration."

`select * from index:Address.full where key lucene "4*"`
=> no results

additionally:
`select count(*) from index:Address.full` => returns 0 as the count, which means for some reason Lucene doesn't create an index. There's no error message when creating the index.

---

How can I accomplish this?

Is there a way to debug the queries as to why no results?

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare the different indices referring to the single field, then type in queries performing this should work:

```
select * from Address where ZIP lucene "4*" and street lucene "a*"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but it is not what I'm looking for. I was probably not clear in my request. Let me clarify it:
I want to be able to have a search with a query that finds a record regardless of whether the searched word is in the street, city, ZIP or state fields. 
In other words I want the users to be able to easily search without having to specify which part of the address they are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

The indexing works as expected in the given form **PROVIDING** there are no constraints on the fields!!

---

After a very thorough investigation, I found the underlying bug!

Some of my fields had constraints. For example, the ZIP had a MAX=10 constraint. Lucene (or some part of OrientDB's indexing) has a bug which causes it to silently fail and create an empty index when there's a MAX constraint on a string field.

I submitted a bug report on this issue and hopefully it will get fixed shortly:
https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6149